# about @import in css

Tags: css, import

I think I divide it because css grew big, and to do import.

```
@import url("aaa.css"); 
       .
       .
       .
@import url("zzz.css");
```

is there be the number of the upper limits of import files?

Comment: What do you mean? Please clarify your question.

Comment: IE can use only 31 .css files. If you need you can import from .css files. Inner limits, I do not know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Internet Explorer has a maximum of 32 @imports. There is even a limit of ~288kb per css file.

Firefox and Opera should not be limited.

Comment: I think if you hit those limits, you might want to rethink your css :D

Comment: I could not find any evidence for a 288KB limit. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49683077/is-there-a-css-file-size-limit-in-ie9/49784811#49784811